# Git ignore dir but unignore files in dir

Tags: git

Yes, this is a duplicate question. But the answers thus far are not working for me. I'm running git v 2.6.4 on osX.

Here's my `.gitignore`:

```
/src/artwork/dist
/dist/*
!/dist/dandelion.yml
```

For line 2, I've also tried `/dist/**`, but running `git status` still does not show `/dist/dandelion.yml`.

*Note that `/dist` is also a git repo, and I'd like to avoid using `git add -f` if I have to. To me forcing means you're doing something wrong.*

Comment: Do you have two `dist` directories or just the one under `/src/artwork/`? Also, are you saying you've got one git repo nested inside another?

Comment: There are two `dist` directories: one inside root at `/dist` and one inside `/src/artwork/`. And, yes, `/dist/` is a repo nested inside the main repo of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding `.gitignore` to each **folder** you want to include the file. Since you have multiple dist folders you should place `.gitignore` with a specific rules per folder.

If i understood you correctly this is your folder structure:

```
|
|-dist
.
.
|-src
   |- artwork
         |- dist
```

#### What you have done so far:

```
# ignore the dist folder under src/artwork
/src/artwork/dist

# ignore dist folder under the root folder
/dist/*

# DO NOT ignore the dandelion.yml under the root/dist folder
!/dist/dandelion.yml
```

> Note that /dist is also a git repo,

Why not adding it as submodule? This will save you the need to add the desired files to the `.gitignore` & its make much more sense if its an inner repo.

---

#### `submodule`

[image]

Comment: The reason for separate repos is because each serves a different purpose. The root repo monitors the entire project. The `/dist` repo is used programmatically by a Ruby gem entitled Dandelion, which uses git to deploy to aws s3.

Comment: still after this comment is can be a separate repo using submodule or subtree. but if you still insist to have it in a 1 big repo is the structure above is the correct one?

Comment: Yes, that is my tree. Is it not possible for a git repo to track files inside another git repo?

Comment: Its a bit tricky. Read this post to see how it can still be done. (The trick is to add the `/` at the end). http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb

Comment: but as a thumbnail git cant track files inside nested git repo unless its a subtree/submodule. so the answer to your previous comment is NO.

Comment: Why then if I remove line 3 from my `.gitignore` (above), and run `git status`, it lists the `/dist/` dir?

Comment: What is the output of `git status` when you change this: `/dist/*` to this: `dist/**`

Comment: Same. It does not list `dandelion.yml`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102855/discussion-between-codewizard-and-jamesjosephfinn).